# Set Zope CookieCrumbler Cookie in Python Script

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies, plone, zope

I know this is an old one to be asking about, but I am trying to figure out a way, through my python login script, to set the CookieCrumbler cookie(s) that are automatically sent to the user upon successful login and visiting a restricted URL.

My goal is to allow my python script to call a zsql method and redirect the user based on their account_type (a column in my db). I have this all working right now, but across two different python scripts. The first logs in the user and redirects to the second script which makes the call to the zsql method and redirects the user accordingly. I would love to be able to do this all in one script, but if the cookies aren't sent the username of that user isn't stored in a cookie and thus cannot be accessed by the zsql method.

I know how to expire the cookies upon logout, but when I change it to setCookie it wants me to define the entire cookie, which of course I need CookieCrumbler to do.

One of my thoughts was to somehow get python to invisibly hit a secure URL and deliver the cookies to the user's browser, sleep for 2 seconds to ensure they got through, and then proceed to the sql stuff.

Another option is what I already mentioned, which is to get CookieCrumbler to send the cookies to the user's browser directly instead of having to try and access a secure URL.

Here's the code I have now:

```
import time
request = container.REQUEST
response = request.response

context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.setCookie('__ac', path='/')
context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.setCookie('__ac_name', path='/')

time.sleep(3)
for user in context.account_data_select():
    if user.account_type == 12 :
        response.redirect("https://secure.mydomain.com/secure/blah")
    else:
        response.redirect("https://secure.mydomain.com/secure")
```

Of course this doesn't work because setCookie requires 3 variables (name, value, options). I do not want to set these manually. I want CookieCrumbler to do its thing and provide the appropriate cookies to the user's browser.

Btw, I am using Zope 2.13.29 and am not using Plone. Just the standard old Zope with Python 2.7.2

Comment: So it turns out this question is meaningless because the cookies are automatically set already by CookieCrumbler once the page returns in the browser (whether it errors out or goes to the secure portion). However, since the single script is running it always gives an error because the page hasn't returned to the browser prior to the "for user in context.account_data_select(): It appears that I need to somehow get these cookies to set in the browser and then move forward with the db call.

Comment: You can still ask Zope questions in the Plone forum, https://community.plone.org where more people will see them and be able to help you... we are one big family now :)